# How do you tamper AuthLogic to show me the "last" last_login_at?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, authlogic

I would like to code the progress of events that have changed since someone had last logged in.

Authlogic provides a `last_login_at`, but that is the datetime of when the user logged in even though he may be currently still logged on.

I'm trying to find the time when they were logged in **before** that. So that when a user logs in, I have a log of the last time they were logged in, and I can show them all the things that have changed since then.

I looked into AuthLogic::Session::MagicColumns which is the method that supports `last_login_at`, but was unable to find anything useful.

Any ideas?

Comment: Actually, last_login_at is set to current_login_at before current_login_at is updated when you login as noted in the comments at the top of the file, lib/authlogic/session/magic_column.rb. So it should be the last login time. I assume your last_login_at field is a datetime type rather than a timestamp, right?

Comment: After looking at the source a bit, I believe @Warren is correct. I hadn't noticed the column differences and your question seemed to elude that `last_lgoin_at` was their current login. As @Warren mentioned `last_login_at` is what you want. `current_login_at` is the most recent login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't read anything like this relating to Authlogic. It seems like you are going to have to write some custom session code to store that datetime you want. You could override the method in Authlogic that sets `last_login_at` and migrate the old value over to your new database column.

Comment: Sounds good to me, but I've never overrode or rewrote a gem before. Not really sure how/where to find that code. Any tips?